# ignore whitespace/identation in annotate mode with Intelliji and git

Tags: git, intellij-idea, blame

`git blame` , on a file , give for each line which was the last commit who have update the line.(like the annotate action on the IDE)

`git blame -w` do the same , but only if the commit do more than indentatation or whitespace.

My issue is, how can I ignore the whitespace with annotate on intelliji?

There is an option for that if I use SVN with Intelliji, but I cannot find-it on git.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IntelliJ uses `git blame -w` by default, as described in this question: [IntelliJ annotate vs git blame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825675/intellij-annotate-vs-git-blame)

But there isn't an option to change this behaviour as it is hardcoded into the IDEA Git plugin.

Answer (score 3):

An option to configure the behavior for git appeared in [2018.3 release](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183867#focus=streamItem-27-2924075-0-0).